# BaseXClient in Python : retrieval problems

Tags: python, basex

I am using BaseX installed on a server in a home network and try to access it using the official BaseXClient from an another machine.

I also have the BaseX GUI installed on the work machine and using Webdav can access the datase on the server.

Here is what ai have for now:

```
from BaseXClient import BaseXClient

# create session
session = BaseXClient.Session('192.168.0.80', 1984, 'admin', 'admin')

try:
    print("\n" + session.execute("list"))
    print("\n" + session.execute("open testdb"))
    print("\n" + session.execute("info db"))
```

The "list" command, correcly lists the availability of `testdb` as the only database on the BaseX server. The open command also seems to complete without a problem. The info command, however, then lists database with it's properties, BUT WITHOUT ANY DOCUMENTS:

```
Database Properties
 NAME: testdb
 SIZE: 55 MB
 NODES: 0
 DOCUMENTS: 0
 BINARIES: 15
 TIMESTAMP: 2020-04-02T22:57:24.000Z
 UPTODATE: true
```

Of course, any following queries also return nothing.

However, I have over 400 documents in the database, which I can access using the GUI. I have looked at the code for BaseXClient, and checked the documentations and examples, but could not find any clues as to what might go wrong here.

---

After writing the above, I noticed that the filesizes on the server are different from what I see in the webdav folder.

Thus, I suspect that the problem is that the changes in the webdav folder to which the GUI is attached to on the client machine, does not sync back to the server. However, if webdav is the problem, then I am still at loss as to how to use the GUI on the client to mange changes on the server, and then to access the info via the python client.

Any support would be highly appreciated.